# Unable to get rid of unwanted links

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I've written a script in VBA to parse some links (connected to `contact` keyword) from a few sites. One link from each site. I used `xmlhttp` requests to accomplish the task. When I execute my script it does parse links from each site. The only problem is that few sites do not have any such links (connected to `contact` keyword) and as a result the output in my excel sheet becomes messy. To be clearer: if any site does not have such link, my scraper fill that column with the previous value. I'm storing those collected links just in the next columns of each search. I hope the below Image will bring you the clarity of what I meant.

This is my try so far:

```
Sub GetConditionalLinks()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, cel As Range, newlink$, R&

    For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            With HTTP
                .Open "GET", cel.Value, False
                .send
                Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With

            For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
                If InStr(1, post.innerText, "contact", 1) > 0 Then newlink = post.getAttribute("href"): Exit For
            Next post
            cel(1, 2) = newlink
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Links I've tried with (I intentionally left few rows blank to see how the script behaves):

```
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/
https://www.houzz.com/professionals/

https://chandoo.org/forum/forums/vba-macros/
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LTIORC8

https://stackoverflow.com/questions
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01LTIORC8
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00GPAFHIO
```

The output I'm having:

[image]
The output I'm expecting to have:

[image]

Search links are in column A and the collected links are in column B. You must have noticed already that the collected links mismatched with the source links because of my looping logic.

***My Question:***

1. How can I fix my loop to get the expected output?
2. What would be the fully qualified line of `cel(1, 2)`,  I meant If I mimic something like `Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("A1")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect you to be able to use something like the following:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetConditionalLinks()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object, i As Long, arr()
    With ActiveSheet
        arr = .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        With HTTP
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                If arr(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
                    .Open "GET", arr(i, 1), False
                    .send
                    Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

                    For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
                        If InStr(1, post.innerText, "contact", 1) > 0 Then arr(i, 2) = post.getAttribute("href"): Exit For
                    Next post
                End If
            Next i
        End With
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Access Denied Sites:

So I started getting access denied so re-wrote as the following. Open to suggestions on improving error handling. It is pretty rudimentary but I was trying to avoid `GoTo` statements.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetConditionalLinks()
    Dim HTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, post As Object, i As Long, arr(), timeoutError As Boolean
    With ActiveSheet
        arr = .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
        With HTTP
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                timeoutError = False
                If arr(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
                    .Open "GET", arr(i, 1), False
                    On Error GoTo Errhand
                    .send
                    If Not timeoutError Then
                        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                        For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
                            If InStr(1, post.innerText, "contact", 1) > 0 Then arr(i, 2) = post.getAttribute("href"): Exit For
                        Next post
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End With
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
    End With
    Exit Sub
Errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147012894 '<== Timeout; especially on access denied sites
            timeoutError = True
            Resume Next
        Case Else '<== Don't know what we are gonna do yet so let's exit
            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Without using an array and looping sheet:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetConditionalLinks()
    Dim HTTP As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument, cel As Range, post As Object, R As Long, timeoutError As Boolean
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cel In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
                R = R + 1: timeoutError = False
                If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
                    HTTP.Open "GET", cel.Value, False
                    On Error GoTo Errhand
                    HTTP.send
                    If Not timeoutError Then
                        Html.body.innerHTML = HTTP.responseText
                        For Each post In Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
                            If InStr(1, post.innerText, "contact", 1) > 0 Then
                                .Cells(R, 2) = post.getAttribute("href"): Exit For
                            End If
                        Next post
                    End If
                End If
        Next cel
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147012894                         '<== Timeout; especially on access denied sites
            timeoutError = True
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        End Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Ain't it possible to accomplish the way I started? My head till spins to see the usage of array. Given a thumbs up.

Comment: Yes but an array is much faster. Think of it this way: I am reading column A and B into an array. You were looping column A but I am storing A, for the same number of rows, and B in memory. Instead of looping the rows in column A in the sheet, I am looping column 1 of the array, issuing the requests and updating column 2 of the array with the contact info (or it is left blank). I then empty the array back to the sheet by saying make cell A1 the same number of rows as the array ubound(arr,1) and same number of columns ubound(arr,2)

Comment: I'll be glad if you do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing like the following? Only difining `newlink = ""` just after the `for loop` within the script should fix the issue:

```
Sub GetConditionalLinks()
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60, HTML As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object, newlink$
    Dim cel As Range, R&

    For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        newlink = ""             '''THIS IS THE FIX
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            With HTTP
                .Open "GET", cel.Value, False
                .send
                HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End With

            For Each post In HTML.getElementsByTagName("a")
                If InStr(1, post.innerText, "contact", 1) > 0 Then newlink = post.getAttribute("href"): Exit For
            Next post
            cel(1, 2) = newlink
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```